# Meaning of "si vivono le stesse memorie"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, translation

I'm reading [an article in Italian](https://www.recensionelibro.it/intervista-erri-de-luca)

> Quali sono i pensieri di uno scrittore? C’è differenza da quelli di un uomo comune o ***si vivono le stesse memorie?***

What does the highlighted part mean in Italian?

Is "si vivono" an impersonal verb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning is to feel the same, to experience the same thoughts and memories (as ordinary people).

About the question about "si vivono" as impersonal verb, you can find on Treccani the [grammatical rules for impersonal verbs](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-impersonali_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/).

> Ci sono poi costrutti verbali impersonali che si possono creare con
>   qualunque verbo, ricorrendo a diverse modalità.
>
> • Il si impersonale (se il verbo è intransitivo o transitivo senza il
>   complemento oggetto espresso)
>
> A casa tua si mangia sempre bene

and it seems this is not your case.

As correctly pointed out by @DaG, in this case the *si*-construction is more precisely the so called “*si passivante*”, in which the verb agrees with its logical object (*si vivono le memorie* = “memories are lived”), as in a passive construction. See [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/costruzione-passiva_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), section 4.

Comment: I'd add that in this case the _si_-construction is more precisely the so called “_si passivante_”, in which the verb agrees with its logical object (_si vivono le memorie_ = “memories are lived”), as in a passive construction. See [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/costruzione-passiva_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), section 4.

Comment: Excuse me, is it incorrect to say that "si vivono" means "to experience"?

Comment: @keramus: In this context, I would say it means "are experienced" because it's a passive construction ("memories are experienced"). Have a look at [this site](http://www.viv-it.org/schede/si-passivante).